# Get object data from pList and populate in cellForIndexPath

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to get the child element `SHOP` from a plist. The plist is as so :

[image]

Settings is a section.

I tried using the following but not sure how to put it in a cellForIndexPath

```
NSDictionary *region = [self.dict valueForKey:@"Settings"];
NSString *name = [region valueForKey:@"Shop"];
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

My Plist is as so:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.dict = tempDict;

NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
self.namesArray = tempArray;

self.sectionArray = [self.dict allKeys];
```

Comment: `Settings` is an array, but you are sending `-objectForKey:` to it. It must crash.

Comment: how would i put it in a cellforindexpath?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to read the **"Shop"** array from the **"item 0"** dictionary you need to do the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.dict = tempDict;

NSArray *settingsArray = self.dict[@"Settings"];
NSDictionary *itemDict = settingsArray[0];
NSArray *shopArray = itemDict[@"Shop"];
```

Of course you should check that the keys and indexes you're using are valid before indexing to avoid crashes.